# delete items from path environment variable

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, path

I have a question regarding editing the path environment variable on my windows 7 Machine.  I have been editing my path using `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`'s dialog window, but the changes i make are not reflected when I type `echo %PAtH%` on the command line.  It shows my additions of path variables, but does not remove the unwanted path variables I deleted.  How do I get `echo %PATH%` and the advanced system properties to display the same path variables?

Thanks in advance,

dubbbdan

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that after making changes you are exiting and re-launching the command prompt where you are testing with your echo.

Comment: I have closed and reopened the cmd prompt.  I think it has something to do with my user account.  If i open the cmd prompt as an administrator I see the correct `PATH`, but as a standard user I see the correct `PATH` with all of the variables I have deleted from the `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` dialog window.  I tried this [solution](http://serverfault.com/questions/300544/environment-variables-in-path-not-expanded-for-non-admin-command-prompt) with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User environment variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100843)

> User environment variables can be viewed from Control Panel as well.
>   The user may add, delete or modify the environment variables in the
>   User Environment Variables for User field. These variables take
>   precedence over system environment variables. The **user path is
>   appended to the system path**.

Next commands could help to identify the problem (return system-level defined `path` and user-level defined `path`, respectively):

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path
```

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ!  That certainly seems to explain the difference between system and user path variables.